# Numba incorrectly interpreting generator functions

Tags: python, generator, numba

I'm having some trouble JIT-ing a generator function with Numba, despite [Numba supposedly having support for generator functions](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.18.1/developer/generators.html). Specifically, I'm trying to implement Heap's algorithm for generating permutations of an array given that Numba doesn't work with the itertools package (basically just copying pseudocode from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm)):

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


@njit()
def permutations(arr):

    c = np.zeros(arr.shape[0], dtype=np.int64)
    yield arr
    i = 0
    while i < arr.shape[0]:
        if c[i] < i:
            if i % 2 == 0:
                temp = arr[1]
                arr[1] = arr[i]
                arr[i] = temp
            else:
                temp = arr[c[i]]
                arr[c[i]] = arr[i]
                arr[i] = temp
            yield arr
            c[i] += 1
            i = 0
        else:
            c[i] = 0
            i += 1


def main():

    arr = np.array(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
    for permutation in permutations(arr):
        print(permutation)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Without `njit()`, the output is correct:

```
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
['B' 'A' 'C' 'D']
['B' 'C' 'A' 'D']
['C' 'B' 'A' 'D']
['C' 'A' 'B' 'D']
['A' 'C' 'B' 'D']
['D' 'C' 'B' 'A']
['C' 'D' 'B' 'A']
['C' 'B' 'D' 'A']
['B' 'C' 'D' 'A']
['B' 'D' 'C' 'A']
['D' 'B' 'C' 'A']
['D' 'A' 'C' 'B']
['A' 'D' 'C' 'B']
['A' 'C' 'D' 'B']
['C' 'A' 'D' 'B']
['C' 'D' 'A' 'B']
['D' 'C' 'A' 'B']
['D' 'C' 'B' 'A']
['C' 'D' 'B' 'A']
['C' 'B' 'D' 'A']
['B' 'C' 'D' 'A']
['B' 'D' 'C' 'A']
['D' 'B' 'C' 'A']
```

However, with `njit()`, I get this:

```
['A' 'B' 'C' 'D']
['B' 'A' 'C' 'D']
```

Is there something special I need to do to JIT a generator function? Am I using the output of the generator incorrectly for how Numba interprets it? Is this a bug in the Numba implementation of generator functions?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with `numba 0.51.2`, `python 3.7.12` on `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS`. Works as expected.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I've got numba 0.51.1 and python 3.9.5 on Windows 10, I'll try updating numba to 0.51.2 to see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Comparing the code on wikipedia it should be `arr[0], arr[i] = arr[i], arr[0]` (swaping for even *i*). Sometimes the IPython kernel shuts down and the execution time varies from 2.5ms to 32ms, that's strange.

Comment: It's the standard google colab installation, might be a custom built by google.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I read it wrong, I have Numba 0.55.1 lol which seems to be the most recent build I can find

Comment: Perhaps related to unfixed generator's [memory leaks](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/6993), removed issue from `numba 0.55 rc`, but that's only a wild guess.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.